# How to call a specific JavaScript function even if they have the same signatures?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, function-call, function-signature

I have a specific situation. I hope you can help me..

I have two different html pages. I am parsing them and regenerating them as a single html page with Java. Each page contains many JavaScript functions and some of them have exactly the same function signature.

The problem is that I should not make any changes on the function definitions that I am parsing from that two different pages.

So, lets say 
Page A has

```
function showMessage(){
alert("Page A");
}
```

Page B has

```
function showMessage(){
alert("Page B");
}
```

When I parse them, function definitions should stay as they are.

I tried to create namespaces for each page's JavaScript functions in the single HTML page and I tried to use object literals. But I should not make any changes in the function definitions. So, following code does not help me..

```
var NS1 = {
    showMessage: function() {

        alert("workss");
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how i can solve this issue?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: You will have to give them different names. Otherwise the function will be overwritten with the definition of the one that comes last.

Comment: You've got a typo on your Page B example:  **showMassage**